# Get latest version of Maven with curl

Tags: bash, maven, curl

My task is to grab latest version of maven in bash script using curl https://apache.osuosl.org/maven/maven-3/
Output should be: 3.8.5

curl -s "https://apache.osuosl.org/maven/maven-3/" | grep -o "[0-9].[0-9].[0-9]" | tail -1
works for me ty

Comment: First why do you use apache.osuosl.org ? Why not let you redirect via https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi furthermore do you check the SHA512... ? Is that on a CI setup ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to

- Use [grep](/questions/tagged/grep) to only get the lines containing the `folder` link
- Use [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) with an regex to get only the version number
- Use `sort` to sort the lines
- Use `tail -n1` to get the last line

```bash
curl -s https://apache.osuosl.org/maven/maven-3/ \
    | grep folder \
    | gsed -E 's/.*([[:digit:]]\.[[:digit:]]\.[[:digit:]]).*/\1/' \
    | sort \
    | tail -n1
```

Output:

```
3.8.5
```

Answer (score 0):

The url you're mentioning is an HTML-document and `curl` is not an HTML-parser, so I'd look into an HTML-parser, like [xidel](/questions/tagged/xidel), if I were you:

```
$ xidel -s "https://apache.osuosl.org/maven/maven-3/" -e '//pre/a[last()]'
3.8.5/

$ xidel -s "https://apache.osuosl.org/maven/maven-3/" -e 'substring-before(//pre/a[last()],"/")'
3.8.5
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use the central repository instead one of the apache maven sites because the information on central more maded for machine consumption.

It will be taken into account that the file `maven-metadata.xml` contains the appropriate information.

There are two options using the **<version>..</version>** tag and the **<latest>..</latest>** tag.

```
MVNVERSION=$(curl https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven/maven-metadata.xml \
| grep "<version>.*</version>" \
| tr -s " " \
| cut -d ">" -f2 \
| cut -d "<" -f1 \
| sort -V -r \
| head -1)
```

The second option:

```
MVNVERSION=$(curl https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven/maven-metadata.xml \
| grep "<latest>.*</latest>" \
| cut -d ">" -f2 \
| cut -d "<" -f1)
```